# Issue with Edittext inputType & Focus Android N (7.0)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-inputtype

Issue with the keyboard, In the code the inputType is set to number but the keyboard showing is of the type text with multiline. Issue is only showing in the Android N (7.0)

The EditText is inside the header of a Listview. In all other versions of android its working perfect.

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardlist_footer, listView, false);
```

In this editText when the keyboard focus comes to it, the focus jumps to the first editText in the page. It prevents the number to be entered

```
<EditText           
  android:id="@+id/editCardNumber"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight=".6"
  android:background="@drawable/drawable_edittext_bg"
  android:hint="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
  android:inputType="number"
  android:maxLength="19"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
  android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
```

In this editText InputType is not Working.In the code the inputType is set to number but the keyboard showing is of the type text with multiline

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editSearchZipCode"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="@null"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:hint="Enter Zip"
  android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
  android:inputType="number"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:textColor="@android:color/black"
  android:textColorHint="#9c9c9c" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add **[android:digits](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits)**

> If set, specifies that this TextView has a numeric input method and
>   that these specific characters are the ones that it will accept. If
>   this is set, numeric is implied to be true .

```
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789"
```

**EDIT**

It's a Dev level **#BUG**.

> Open a bug report from Android Studio by selecting Help > Submit
>   Feedback. This is the easiest way to start a bug because it populates
>   the bug report with your Android Studio version, Java version, and
>   system information, which we need to properly reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AshwinSAshok have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146941/android-inputtype-phone-not-working

Comment: Not Working. :(

Comment: @AshwinSAshok It's a bug probably . Check `FYI` .

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:2017年11月6日 17:52:19

**@deprecated** 
in Android 7.1 Version had some issue !

---

try this,Use it at your own risk.

```
/**
 * 尝试性修复了在ListView里显示EditText InputType为 其它非text 类型时，弹出的软键盘会从数字键盘自动切换为 英文全键盘 的问题。
 */
class ListViewEx2 extends ListView
{
    public ListViewEx2(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ListViewEx2(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ListViewEx2(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ListViewEx2(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr, final int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b)
    {
        //经过初步测试，只有在Android 7.0平台以上的系统才会出现软键盘自动切换的问题。
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
        //仅仅在 changed 为 true 时再调用,这样就可以避免了.
        if (changed)
            super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        }
        else
            super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    }
}
```